# Problema ao diminuir o tamanho de uma pilha em c

Tags: c, stack

Esse programa é um exercício para se trabalhar com pilhas, está tudo certo, mas quando eu diminuo tamanho da pilha pra excluir o ultimo termo ele aparece no penúltimo elemento do vetor.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

typedef struct viagem {
  char nome[50];
  char uf[2];
}v;

typedef struct pilha{
  int topo;
  int distancia;
  int visitadas;
  v cidades[10];
}p;

void empilhar (p *pilha) {
  int dist;
  system("cls");
  pilha->topo++;
  printf("Cidade destino: " );
  scanf("%[^\n]s",&pilha->cidades[pilha->topo].nome );
  printf("UF: " );
  scanf("%s",&pilha->cidades[pilha->topo].uf );
  printf("Distancia: " );
  scanf("%i",&dist);
  pilha->visitadas++;
  pilha->distancia=pilha->distancia+dist;
}
void desempilhar (p *pilha){
  pilha->topo--;
}
int main (){
  p pilha;
  pilha.topo=-1;
  pilha.visitadas = 0;
  pilha.distancia = 0;
  int flag=1;
  int opc;
  do {
    system ("cls");
    if (pilha.topo == -1) {
      printf("Voce esta em Maringa-Pr !");
    }
    else {
      printf("Voce esta em %s-%s",pilha.cidades[pilha.topo].nome,pilha.cidades[pilha.topo].uf);
    }
    printf("\nVoce visitou %i cidades", pilha.visitadas );
    printf("\nVoce percoreu %ikm\n", pilha.distancia );
    printf("\n1-Avancar");
    printf("\n2-Voltar");
    printf("\n3-Sair");
    printf("\nopcao: " );
    scanf("%i%*c",&opc );
    switch (opc) {
      case 1:
        empilhar (&pilha);
      break;
      case 2:
        desempilhar (&pilha);
      break;
      case 3:
        flag=0;
      break;
    }
  } while(flag);
  printf("Programa finalizado ! " );
  scanf("%*i",&opc);
}
```

Comment: Note que para armazenar 2 caracteres em uma string (caso da UF) você precisa prever espaço para o caractere terminador '\0'. Declare char[3].

Comment: Perfeito ! Muito obrigado

Comment: O problemamente não está exatamente na pilha, explico: a pilha que você implementou guarda apenas as variáveis `v.nome` e `v.uf`, quando você desempilha, esses dados são atualizados e a interface informa corretamente em qual cidade o usuário se encontra. Contudo, a pilha não guarda as variáveis `pilha.distancia` e `pilha.visitadas` e como a função `desempilhar()` não altera esses valores, ao desempilhar, os dados permanecem inalterados.

Comment: a observação do @v.Santos é pertinente

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problema 1:

```
typedef struct viagem {
  char nome[50];
  // char uf[2]; // <-------------- ERRO
  char uf[3];
} v;
```

Problema 2:

```
void desempilhar (p *pilha){
  if (pilha->topo >= 0)  // <------- FALTA
    pilha->topo--;
}
```

E a observação do @v. Santos está correta: distância e "visitadas" deveriam fazer parte de cada elemento da pilha, não apenas um valor para toda a pilha.

Answer (score 1):

Boa tarde Wingeds,

Acredito que exista um problema  conceitual na sua Pilha, que, por definição, são estruturas de dados *LIFO* (*Last in, first out*). Elas podem ser implementadas, dentre outras formas, através de **Vetores dinâmicos** e de **Listas encadeadas**.

No caso que você apresentou o que pude perceber é que você está usando a instancia de um TAD para armazenar dados nele, mas isso conceitualmente não é uma pilha.

***Ilustração de uma pilha abaixo***

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Voltando para o seu problema:**

As operações de Inserir (*Push*) e Remover (*Pop*) na pilha vão variar de acordo com o modelo que você está utilizando. No caso de vetores  o *Pop* é através de um "Apagar lógico", que se trata de voltar uma posição no "Topo" da pilha, sem necessariamente remover o valor, e o *Push* será sobrescrevendo esses valores anteriores ou inserindo valores em espaços vazios. No caso de listas encadeadas o *Push* é através de alocação dinâmica, famoso `malloc()`, onde você vai alocar o espaço de uma célula (*TAD*) e o ligar no topo da lista, e o *Pop* se dá através da função `free()`, onde você vai liberar o espaço alocado para a célula que deseja apagar, tomando cuidado, claro, para não perder a referência do valor anterior.

***Ilustração abstratas de Push e Pop***

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Caso minha observação esteja incorreta e a sua atividade se trate realmente de usar a instancia do seu *struct* para armazenar seus dados favor sinalizar para que eu possa apagar a resposta!

Abraços e bons estudos!

Comment: Discordo. O que define uma pilha não é a natureza do vetor utilizado na sua implementação, mas sim o respeito à logica LIFO. No presente caso, o sujeito que fez a pergunta implementou uma pilha estática - que infelizmente tem lá seus problemas -  e, portanto, não faz o menor sentido o uso de malloc() para a alocação dinâmica de memória.

Comment: Boa tarde @v.Santos, acho que houve um desentendimento da sua parte. Primeiramente: Em nenhum momento eu disse que o que **DEFINE** a pilha é o uso de vetores dinâmicos, eu disse que são estruturas de dados do tipo LIFO e que **PODEM SER IMPLEMENTADAS ATRAVÉS** de vetores dinâmicos, pois de fato é possível. O questionamento sobre a estrutura dele ser uma pilha se deu pelo fato dos dados não estarem separados para serem removidos ou inseridos seguindo o conceito que apresentei. Mas obrigado pela observação, irei editar para ficar mais claro e evitar desentendimentos futuros, abraços!

Comment: Não creio que seja um caso de "desentendimento da minha parte", na realidade, eu realmente não concordo com a sua resposta e mesmo após os seus esclarecimentos continuo não concordando. Explico: as suas referências às implementações de uma pilha dinâmica, no mínimo, não se relacionam à pergunta, já que não faz o menor sentido usar `malloc()` e `free()` no código apresentado. E a sua concepção de que não se deve usar uma "instância de uma struct" para armazenar dados em uma pilha é, no mínimo, equivocada. Abraços @H.Lima.